# Compile Latex with Github Actions

Tags: latexmk, git, docker

I'm writing my master thesis in latex and I'm using git and github for version control. To compile it on my laptop, I have this Makefile and to compile it I just run `make` and everything works fine.

```
.PHONY: main clean FORCE

main: thesis clean

thesis: FORCE
    latexmk -auxdir=tmp -outdir=tmp -pdflatex='texfot lualatex -interaction nonstopmode' -pdf thesis.tex
    mv tmp/thesis.pdf .

clean:
    rm -rf tmp
```

However, my idea was to have a github action that compiles this document whenever code is commited to github. And to do so, I have this github action that simply runs the makefile

```
name: "build"

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: build
        run: make
```

But when I push to the repository, the document is not compiled because the github action does not run properly. I get this error `make: latexmk: Command not found`. From what I've looked up on google, I can have a dockerfile with latexmk and then simply run docker to compile the document. But I can't figure out how to do this. Has anyone ever done something similar to this?

Comment: you could use a texlive docker or use apt to install latxmk into the ubuntu instance running your action

Comment: we don't use latexmk but for example the github workflow for the main latex3/latex2e repository has `- run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ghostscript` to install ghostscript, latexmk would be similar. https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/develop/.github/workflows/main.yaml#L66